# How can I positioning LI elements to the bottom of UL list

Tags: html, css, positioning, html-lists

I have menu items like: Row1 Row2.. RowN and I want them not to be that wide - that's why including breaks (with max-width)

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>Row1</li>
  <li>Row1 Row2 Row3</li>
  <li>Row1</li>
  <li>Row1 Row 2</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
/* MENU */

.menudiv {padding-left:10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d0db88;}

ul.menu
{                 
    list-style-type: none;
    min-width: 1050px;
    position: relative;
    left:10px;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;       
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li
{    
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li a
{    
    float: left;    
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 9px 12px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width:130px;
}
```

Actual:

```
+--------------------+
|Row1 Row1 Row1 Row1 |
|     Row2      Row2 |
|     Row3           |
+--------------------+
```

What I need:

```
+--------------------+
|     Row1           |
|     Row2      Row1 |
|Row1 Row3 Row1 Row2 |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: This may or may not be a question better suited for Doctype.com.

Comment: How can I migrate it to the other forum?

Comment: The following question deals with migrating questions, but it seems you cannot do it yourself immediately. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-to-migrate-a-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`:

```
ul.menu
{                 
   vertical-align: bottom;
}

ul.menu li
{    
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
}
```

EDIT: Added `text-align: center;`. If I understand your comment correctly, that is what you want. If not, you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: I've got this problem yet: If the menu item is Word & LongWord, the second one will be aligned left (LongWord) and I need to have them both centered..

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/
This link might help, alternatively you could create the result as table based content with the content aligned to the bottom of each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that following is your html

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Row1</a></li>
        <li><a>Row1 Row2 Row3</a></li>
        <li><a>Row1</a></li>
        <li><a>Row1 Row 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can simply style your CSS as following

```
li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;       
}

li a {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Above code should work across browsers (I have not tested this across browsers)