# Align a list and push text to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I've a 3 boxes list with title, border and brief description.

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

I would like using only CSS to align the green borders and push all the one row titles to the bottom.

The contents and titles are dynamic so, can happen that there will be 1, 2, 3 rows for the title but I always want that titles with less rows starts from the bottom like in the example below.

[image]

I can not use Javascript!

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

---

At the moment the code structure is this:

HTML:

```
<section id="" class="boxes">
                <ul class="inline">
                    <li>
                        <article>
                            <h2>Mae hyn yn enghraifft prif llawer hwy</h2>
                            <p>
                                Mae llawer o bethau gwych cymaint yn mynd ymlaen yr haf hwn a, beth bynnag yw eich cynlluniau, nawr yw'r amser i fynd i'r afael a eich gwariant.
                            </p>
                            <a class="read-more" href="">Read more &gt;</a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
```

CSS:

```
ul.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 978px;
}

    ul.inline li {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 18px 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 308px;
    }

        ul.inline li h2 {
            border-bottom: 5px solid #34750E;
            color: #34750E;
            font-size: 21px;
            margin: 0 0 10px;
            padding: 0 0 10px;
            position: relative;
        }

        ul.inline li a.read-more {
                color: #34750E !important;
        }
```

---

EDIT:

**[FIDDLE UP HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/99srG/)**

Comment: What you have tried? create an example at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: do you have some example code?  While you're at it, could you post it as a demo on http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com

Comment: You do not wish to use <table> ? It can be easily accomplished using table.

Comment: no table please. I can use display: table and everything, but not table in the markup. I'm going to build a fiddle.

Comment: Fiddle is up on my edit and here: [http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/99srG/](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/99srG/)

Comment: @AndreaTurri: Actually, I think a table would be a fine solution for you in this case.

Comment: @Truth I can not use tables but I can choose to remove the list and use only divs if it helps.

Comment: If you're refusing to use JS and tables, then I think you will have to separate the titles from the content, have a div that has all your h2 in it, and set h2 height:100% and align the text to the bottom then.

Comment: @AndreaTurri: Don't force an unsemantic element into your purposes. If you have access to the markup, you can use a table. Don't impose imaginary constraints on yourself.

Comment: @AndreaTurri - Check my answer if it fits your requirement.

Comment: @Truth is not my choose to don't use tables. I can not do that.

Comment: @AndreaTurri: What imposes that restriction on you?

Comment: @AndreaTurri: Your boss hired you because you're supposed to be the expert, not because you're a highly trained monkey with a keyboard. Go to your boss and burst his bubble, tables are not evil. Tables for layout is evil. This is not tables for layout. It's tables for tabular data.

Comment: @Truth I know that, I think the same, I talked with him many times for that but the final answer is that I can not use tables! :) And for this reason I need the help from this fantastic community!

Comment: @AndreaTurri - Check my updated answer using the markup as rendered out in your question.

Comment: @AndreaTurri: Stupid table hating boss, .net, you must really love where you work :P I'm just sayin'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Check this updated fiddle that uses the markup as in your question: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/hmCuj/

Solution logic is basically remains the same.

---

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/5hhdE/1/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="headings">
    <li>Heading #1. Heading #1. Heading #1. Heading #1. Heading #1. </li>
    <li>Heading #2</li>
    <li>Heading #3. Heading #3. Heading #3. Heading #3. Heading #3. Heading #3. Heading #3.</li>
</ul>
<ul class="matter">
    <li>Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. </li>
    <li>Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. </li>
    <li>Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. Matter. </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.headings, ul.matter {
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.headings li {
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #888888;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 33.3%;
}
ul.matter li {
    width: 33.3%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

*Got the idea from this post*: [How can I positioning LI elements to the bottom of UL list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510401/how-can-i-positioning-li-elements-to-the-bottom-of-ul-list)

Comment: There is a '.Net foreach' that repeat a list and push inside title and content. As I wrote in my post, it is dynamic.. If I have 2 lists how can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you'll have multiple `UL`s inside a `section` with class boxes? If so you'll need a different solution!

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it's highly not semantic. A user with a screen reader will see 2 different lists with no apparent link between them. While it looks good, it has drawbacks.

Comment: @Truth - That is correct. The only good i see in this is that it will work with the output of the `foreach` server code whose output i assume is not under the OP's control.

Comment: @techfoobar your update is ok. I'm just wondering in terms of cross-browsing what happens using `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` on the list... but I will try. ps: You don't need to set the `white-space: no-wrap/normal` if you use a fixed width on the `li`.

Answer (score 2):

I've set up an example using tables. This is tabular data, it has a header line, and a description line, and multiple columns.

**[Live Example](http://codepen.io/RikudoSennin/pen/ulpca)**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Event Title 1</th>
      <th>Event Title 2<br>Mutliline</th>
      <th>Event Title 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Event 1 description<br>Multiline!</td>
      <td>Event 2 description</td>
      <td>Event 3 description</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
th td {
  margin: 5px;
}
th {
  border-bottom: green 2px solid;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a CSS table?

http://jsfiddle.net/CeMrZ/

I've not included all of the font colouring etc. Just the layout code.

**CSS**

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.table>ul {
    display: table-row;
}
.table>ul>li {
    display: table-cell;
}
.table>ul.thead>li{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <ul class="thead">
        <li>Mae hyn yn enghraifft prif llawer hwy</li>
        <li>Mae hyn yn enghraifft prif llawer hwy<br />Mae hyn yn enghraifft prif llawer hwy</li>
        <li>Mae hyn yn enghraifft prif llawer hwy</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Mae llawer o bethau gwych cymaint yn mynd ymlaen yr haf hwn a, beth bynnag yw eich cynlluniau, nawr yw'r amser i fynd i'r afael a eich gwariant.</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3<br />Mae llawer o bethau gwych cymaint yn mynd ymlaen yr haf hwn a, beth bynnag yw eich cynlluniau, nawr yw'r amser i fynd i'r afael a eich gwariant.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This It works:

HTML Code:

```
<section class="boxes">
    <ul class="inline">
        <li>
            <article>
                <h2>Mae hyn yn enghraifft prif llawer hwy</h2>
                <p>Mae llawer o bethau gwych cymaint yn mynd ymlaen yr haf hwn a, beth bynnag yw eich cynlluniau, nawr yw'r amser i fynd i'r afael a eich gwariant.</p>
                <a class="read-more" href="">Read more &gt;</a>
            </article>
        </li>
        <li>
            <article>
                <h2>green borders and push</h2>
                <p>Mae llawer o bethau gwych cymaint yn mynd ymlaen yr haf hwn a, beth bynnag yw eich cynlluniau, nawr yw'r amser i fynd i'r afael a eich gwariant.</p>
                <a class="read-more" href="">Read more &gt;</a>
            </article>
        </li>
        <li>
            <article>
                <h2>with less rows starts from the bottom like in the example</h2>
                <p>Mae llawer o bethau gwych cymaint yn mynd ymlaen yr haf hwn a, beth bynnag yw eich cynlluniau, nawr yw'r amser i fynd i'r afael a eich gwariant.</p>
                <a class="read-more" href="">Read more &gt;</a>
            </article>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

CSS Code:

```
ul.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 978px;
}
ul.inline li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 18px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 308px;
}
ul.inline li p{
    border-top: 5px solid #34750E;
}
ul.inline li h2 {
    color: #34750E;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
}
ul.inline li a.read-more {
    color: #34750E !important;
}
```